# bash script - seeking advice on extracting columns from csv file and how to skip to next line in current while loop

Tags: bash, csv

im tasked by my company to write a bash script to extract column(s) from the given csv file. The csv file contain multiple columns but 1 of the column is rather tricky to extract.

Example column for the csv:

**(some column)...Column1,Column2,TrickyColumn,Column3,...(more column)**

example column data:

**...1,2,"fk,this,column",3,....**

i looked up on the internet, most of them suggest to use awk or cut and specify the delimiter to comma to extract the data, but some record contain comma in that trickkcolumn, which mess up my columns extraction. Tried quotation mark, but some record have them as well.

here is how i do it

```
while read line 
#read each csv record to line
do
    commaPosition=$(expr index "$line" ,) #find the comma position  
    extractedColumn=${line:0:$((commaPosition-1))} #get the column data by using substring 
    column1="$extractedColumn" #store the column in variable to later use

    line=${line:$CommaPosition} #substring and overwrite the line record so now the line record is : 2,"fk,this,column",3,...
    commaPosition=$(expr index "$line" ,)   
    extractedColumn=${line:0:$((commaPosition-1))}
    column2="$extractedColumn"

    line=${line:$CommaPosition} #line now = "fk,this,column",3,....
    line=$(rev<<<$line)           #reverse the line to better extract the tricky column
                                  #reversed line = "3,"nmuloc,siht,kf"
    commaPosition=$(expr index "$line" ,)           
    extractedColumn=${line:0:$((commaPosition-1))}          
    column3=$(rev<<<$extractedColumn     #revert the reversed column back to readable state and store to variable

    line=${line:$nextCommaPosition}   #line now= "nmuloc,siht,kf"       
    extractedColumn="$line"           #extract the tricky column last and reverse it to store
    trickyColumn=$(rev<<<$extractedColumn)
done <csv
```

as the code above, i grab the tricky column by extracting the column infront and behind before getting the tricky column. But right now i ran into some other problem.

Most of the time the record in the csv file are presented line by line which is fine for column extraction. But some record are presented in multiple line which break my script. Like this:

```
 **...1,2,"fk,
 this,
 column",3,....**
```

as oppose to single line

```
 **...1,2,"fk,this,column",3,....**
```

So the questions is:

1. is there any way to extract the columns more efficiently?
2. how to modify the script in case the record spammed in multiple line?

*forgive my poor English and thanks for any help given :)

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: You should be using a language with a proper CSV parser, not `bash`, `awk`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps you to solve the problem of the new lines. Using awk you can define what the field separator FS is (in this case a `,` or a `,\n`) and what the record separator RS is (in this case any character that is not a `,` followed by a `\n`)

**Reference:** http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/

***-------------------------------
test.csv***
(each csv line ends with a blank space and then a linebreak. For example, there is a blank space after the 6, the 12 and the 18)

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
7,8,9,
10,11,12
13,
14,
15,
16,
17,
18
```

--------------------------------------------
**Command:**
`awk 'BEGIN { RS="[^,]\n";FS=",\|,\n";ORS="\n";OFS=","} { print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'  test.csv`
**Output:**
`1,2,3,4,5,6
7,8,9,10,11,12
13,14,15,16,17,18`

For the problem that a `,` is inside a string (and does not delimit a new field) , I guess you could replace the FS to a more complex regex that detects those cases